# Firebase, how observe works?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I honestly I have tried to figure out when to call ref.removeAllObservers or ref.removeObservers, but I'm confused. I feed I'm doing something wrong here.

```
var noMoreDuplicators = [String]()
func pull () {
    if let myIdi = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    ref.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        if let userers = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
            for (_, velt) in userers {
                let newUser = usera()
                if let thierId = velt["uid"] as? String {
                    if thierId != myIdi {
                if let userName = velt["Username"] as? String, let name = velt["Full Name"] as? String, let userIdent = velt["uid"] as? String {
                    newUser.name = name
                    newUser.username = userName
                    newUser.uid = userIdent

                    if self.noMoreDuplicators.contains(userIdent) {
                        print("user already added")
                    } else {
                        self.users.append(newUser)
                        self.noMoreDuplicators.append(userIdent)
                    }
                }
                    }
                }
            }
            self.tableViewSearchUser.reloadData()
        }

    })

    ref.removeAllObservers()
    }
}
```

Am I only supposed to call removeAllObservers when observing a single event, or...? And when should I call it, if call it at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From official documentation for `observe(_:with:)` :

> This method is used to listen for data changes at a particular location. This is
>   the primary way to read data from the Firebase Database. Your block
>   will be triggered for the initial data and again whenever the data
>   changes.

Now since this method will be triggered everytime the data changes, so it depends on your usecase , if you want to observe the changes in the database as well, if not then again from the official documentation:

> Use `removeObserver(withHandle:)` to stop receiving updates.

Now if you only want to observe the database once use `observeSingleEvent(of:with:)` , again from official documentation:

> This is equivalent to observe:with:, except the block is
>   immediately canceled after the initial data is returned

Means that you wont need to call `removeObserver(withHandle:)` for this as it will be immediately canceled after the initial data is returned.

Now lastly , if you want to remove all observers , you can use this `removeAllObserver` but note that:

> This method removes all observers at the current reference, but does
>   not remove any observers at child references. removeAllObservers must
>   be called again for each child reference where a listener was
>   established to remove the observers

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need to call `removeAllObservers` when you're observing a single event, because this observer get only called once and then immediately removed.

If you're using `observe(.value)` or `observe(.childAdded)`, and others though, you would definitely need to remove all your observers before leaving the view to preserve your battery life and memory usage.

You would do that inside the `viewDidDisappear` or `viewWillDisappear` method, like so:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    // Remove your observers here:

    yourRef.removeAllObservers()

}
```

Note: you could also use `removeObserver(withHandle:)` method.

Comment: Is it ok to run observer outside the view controller, like not removeObserver in view will disappear?

Comment: Well no it's not something you would like to do if you're using an observer that is not observeSingleEvent(), because you would end up having many observers running at the same time even though, for some of them, you won't be using it anymore. So I believe it's always a good practice to call removeAllObservers on the refs you're observing at.